# Select and import dataframes into a list from the global environment

Tags: r, list, dataframe, import

I would like to select and import ca. 30 dataframes from my global environment into a list.
All my dataframes end with ".AM", therefore should be very easy to import them but I am still quite new to R.

I tried:

```
mylist <- list(pattern = "*.AM")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames). See the answers here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the datasets in a `list`.

```
mget(ls(pattern =  "*.AM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for

```
mylist <- ls(pattern = ".AM")
```

which returns `mylist` as a vector of the matching object names

Answer (score 0):

try to set the working directory to wherever the files are saved

```
setwd("C:\\user\\files")
```

then create a list of the .AM dataframes

```
mylist = list.files(pattern="*.AM")
```

I guess that should work?